# Wordpress won't allow we to register menus

Tags: php, wordpress, menu

I'm making my own custom wordpress theme for the first time and I've hit a snag when trying to register menus.

I've followed a tutorial to build the theme at http://themeshaper.com/2012/10/22/the-themeshaper-wordpress-theme-tutorial-2nd-edition/ and looked it up on http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/06/01/goodbye-headaches-hello-menus but no matter what i do the code that registers the menu won't work as I don't see the menu to add items to in wp-admin.
Here's the function I register them in:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'eastmids_setup' ) ):
/**
 * Sets up theme defaults and registers support for various WordPress features.
 *
 * Note that this function is hooked into the after_setup_theme hook, which runs
 * before the init hook. The init hook is too late for some features, such as indicating
 * support post thumbnails.
 *
 * @since eastmids 1.0
 */
function eastmids_setup() {

/**
 * Custom template tags for this theme.
 */
require( get_template_directory() . '/inc/template-tags.php' );

/**
 * Custom functions that act independently of the theme templates
 */
require( get_template_directory() . '/inc/tweaks.php' );

/**
 * Make theme available for translation
 * Translations can be filed in the /languages/ directory
 * If you're building a theme based on eastmids, use a find and replace
 * to change 'eastmids' to the name of your theme in all the template files
 */
load_theme_textdomain( 'eastmids', get_template_directory() . '/languages' );

/**
 * Add default posts and comments RSS feed links to head
 */
add_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links' );

/**
 * Enable support for the Aside Post Format
 */
add_theme_support( 'post-formats', array( 'aside' ) );

/**
 * This theme uses wp_nav_menu() in one location.
 */
register_nav_menus( array(
    'primary' => __( 'Primary Menu' ),
) );
}
endif; // eastmids_setup
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'eastmids_setup' );
```

And here is how I use it:

```
<nav role="navigation" class="site-navigation main-navigation">
     <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
</nav>
```

What is displayed instead is an ul tag containing Home followed by my pages.

seeing as i can't see the menus in wp-admin i assume the register is failing somehow.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you haven't specified a menu yet.

After you've set up your codes for the menu, you should go to the dashboard and create a menu from there (`Appearance` -> `Menu`). Or you are not seeing this menu either? There's a stray `endif;` in your code, could you post the entire code please?

Enter the menu name, add required items to the menu and click on `Create menu`. Have a look at [Appearance Menus Screen](http://codex.wordpress.org/Appearance_Menus_Screen) to understand how it works.

Comment: Ah I see, I didn't realise the 'primary' name was a handle to a wp_nav_menu call location.
What i thought it was that when i registered the menu it would appear as a menu to add items to in wp-admin, but when i went there and created a new menu i found what you meant in "Theme Location"